# Show pin on the map after clicking the custom button on the pop-up

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arcgis, esri, arcgis-js-api

I am using ArcGIS JS API 4.0 with angular. On the pop-up, I have added the custom button More details, On the click of that button i want to show the pin on the map. I dont find much online examples to achieve this, can anybody help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, your issue is to get the location of click within the action method.

If so, you can get the location from the view.popup.location. which is a point geometry. With that you can add a new Graphic to the layer or on the map. I have not worked with AngularJS. so would not be able to provide you with sample. but with the location details available, it should be easy to find a sample to add a graphic.

Edit:
This sample is more appropriate.
https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/get-started-graphics/index.html

Comment: I want to show a Pin similar to what is shown with the google maps. When i click the feature layer it shows the the pop-up, I have added a custom button to the pop-up , on the click of that button i want to show a pin on the map for that location, similar to what is shown on the google maps. https://www.google.com/maps/place/Fairwood+Greens+Homeowners'+Association/@47.4431266,-122.1181985,14z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x0000000000000000:0xafd533eecd9683ae!8m2!3d47.4543555!4d-122.1100867

Comment: Like I mentioned earlier you can achieve that by adding a Graphic to your view. To get the pin, you can use PictureMarkerSymbol to get that style. Use the xoffset and yoffset properties to make the Point in the image to coincide with the point location.

Comment: Thanks let me try that solution.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your quick response. Your answer really helped. I still find it very difficult to store the pop-up location and then show the pin when the custom button on the pop-up is clicked. If you know then please let me know. However, I have implemented my solution to show the pin as soon as the feature on the map is clicked. Here is the code for that.

```
 self.mapView.on("click", function (event) {
                self.mapView.graphics.removeAll(); 

// I added this line to make sure the previous pin is removed if the new      
//feature is clicked. If there is a better way to handle it, let me know.

                    // Create a symbol for drawing the point
                    var markerSymbol = new SimpleMarkerSymbol({
                        color: [226, 119, 40],
                        outline: { // autocasts as new SimpleLineSymbol()
                            color: [255, 255, 255],
                            width: 2
                        }
                    });

                    // Create a graphic and add the geometry and symbol to it
                    var pointGraphic = new Graphic({
                        geometry: event.mapPoint,
                        symbol: markerSymbol
                    });

                    self.mapView.graphics.addMany([pointGraphic]);

                });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can respond to the `trigger-action` on the popup and then use the `view.popup.location` as already mentioned

```
view.popup.on("trigger-action", function(evt){
  if(evt.action.id === "more-details"){
    // add graphic at view.popup.location
  }
});
```